# filling CommandContributionItem for pulldown menu in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I can create a `CommandContributionItem` programatically as follows :

```
CommandContributionItemParameter param = new CommandContributionItemParameter(serviceLocator, id, commandId, CommandContributionItem.STYLE_PUSH);
CommandContributionItem item = new CommandContributionItem(this);
```

If i change the style `CommandContributionItem.STYLE_PUSH` to `CommandContributionItem.STYLE_PULLDOWN` then I can create pulldown menu in the toolbar instead of push button.

Now my question is how will i fill the `items` into this `ContributionItem`. There is fill method already present on the `CommandContributionItem` object but I want to input other `CommandContributionItem` objects as `menu items`. How  will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. add a menu contribution:

   toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions
2. Add a command which you want to be visible on the pulldown menu under the above toolbar. E.g New Pull down menu. If you click on button directly it will lead you to new wizard. Else you can click on the down arrow.

   suppose ID for thise command is: com.org.new.mywizard
3. add another menu contribution with

   location uri as:menu:com.org.new.mywizard

4.now whichever commands you want to add in dropdown add them under the above mentioned menu contribution

Comment: @ Priyank Thakkar: Thanks for your input. But I am not adding anything in plugin.xml as because based on the combo box on the view i want to completeley change my toolbar items. I am adding all the commands through CommandContributionItem. It is working fine perfectly. But now i want to create CommandContributionItem with pulldown menu and fill it with other CommandContributionItem objects.

Comment: CommandContribution will return an array of IContributionItem. So you menu will be updated each time based on certain conditions. You need to use dyanmic option for menu contribution in that case. Here is an example how to use it: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Populating_a_dynamic_submenu

Comment: I can't even add menu contribution to plugin.xml because i want that menu only when some condition satisfies for the selection of some item in the combo box in the view. (If you add in plugin.xml it will be present always in the view's toolbar)

Comment: u can add it to plugin.xml and set the attribute like enables when and visible when.... isn't it?

Comment: I can do that, but it is tedious job for the scenario i am using. As of now what I am doing is for any combo box change (selectionchanged) completely remove the toolbar items and add what i want to add for that item selected (which is much simpler).

Comment: I agree with you. Solution might be you can use SWT toolbar. Add the toolbar to a toolbar manager and wrap you command with actions. Add these actions to toolbar manager to. I think it should help